# How to collect docker logs to a particular docker container in compose?

Tags: logging, docker, logstash, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose and would like to use the 'gelf' logging driver to send individual container logging to a logstash container defined in the same compose.

Using one of the 'logical' hostnames in 'gelf-address' gives me a not defined error and the (non-optimal) solution using 'ipv4_address' don't seem to work either.

I know that this way I may loose some initial logging messages due to startup sequencing, but that is fine. It makes testing down the road much easier as it contains logging to a particular setup.

Any clever solutions on how to approach this?

Comment: I've had success with logspout. Never heard of gelf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by [@cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007), referring to [logspout](https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout) put me on the right track. It connects directly to `/var/run/docker.sock` and gets the logs from there and as it is running in a normal container, it has all the routing information available.

Only issue is that it appears to only grab the logs from the time it becomes active and so one will miss the really early ones. However, that's a price I'm willing to pay. It's also a pain to connect to [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash), as that one seems to take a VERY long time to come up.

Another good reference was  [Gary A. Stafford's](https://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/author/garystafford/) ["Containerized Microservice Log Aggregation and Visualization using ELK Stack and Logspout"](https://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/tag/logspout/)

Answer (score 0):

Hostname lookups from your composition will be tricky. The service names are held in the Docker internal DNS resolver. The Docker host running the containers is not able to resolve those addresses, so you may need to use the static IP for your logging container.

The Docker host should be able to connect to the container `ipv4_address` over a user defined bridge network as the host assigns the `.1` address to the bridge interface. I'm not sure if that holds true for an overlay network.

You could also make other services [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/depends-on) on the log container so it at least comes up first.

If anyone is using [fluentd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#/fluentd-options) trying this, you might need the `fluentd-async-connect` option so containers don't block trying to open the connection to the logging container.